# How to translate this statement to First Order Logic?

Tags: logic, logic-translation

“Thus there exists a pet in this house being a cat or a dog”

I am unsure of how this statements should be translated.

Comment: I am not sure what "being" means there; it is not normal English grammar.

Comment: @CarlMummert: While awkward, the gerund phrase evidently modifies "pet" to signify that the animal which satisfies "pet in this house" is one or the other kind of animal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $ P(x) $ denote the property that $x$ is a pet in the house , and let $C(x)$ and $D(x)$ be the properties that $x$ is a cat or dog respectively, then your sentences translate to $$ \forall x (P(x) \to (C(x) \lor D(x)))$$ and $$ \to \exists y(P(y) \land(C(y) \lor D(y))) $$

Comment: A first-order formula cannot begin with $\to$.  The "Thus" in the question would not appear if the sentence was written on its own as a formula.

Comment: @CarlMummert:  Perhaps "thus" could be expressed by a [turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)) ?

Comment: The turnstile isn't part of the actual formal language in first-order logic, it's part of the symbolism used in the deductive system. So, for example, if we want to translate a proof line by line into first-order logic, and the last line begins with "therefore", that will disappear when we translate the last line into a first-order formula.  There are many words that are used in natural language math that disappear when we translate into formal languages. @hardmath.